# display wordpress paging only if have two or more pages

Tags: wordpress

How can I modify wp_pagenavi function so if I only got 1 page of results no paging bar will be display.
I want to display the paging bar only if the results is more then 1 pages (2, 3, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Did u read the docs: [Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)?
U can try to add a extra if statement above the pagination.

Comment: Can I add the "if" all over the site.?

Comment: I guess only where u want to do this? Can u make a snippet of your code?

Comment: I don't want to make 20-30 code chnages all over the site .I can modify the code

Comment: Where do u define your code? Not inside the functions.php?

Comment: multiplie  template files

Comment: Why not create a function in your functions.php and call this function inside the multiple templates.